# how can I keep value when click out (ng-selelect)

Tags: angular

I use `ng-select` for input (I use `ng-select` because I want the dropdown)
`ng-select` can only capture the true value when we input, if I input something not in the data.result it can not be keep the input which i wrote before
For example:

```
data {
    abc1,
    abc2,
    abc3
}
```

my input: `[abc]` they will suggest `ac1` to `abc3`
but when I type `xyz` it wont keep the `xyz` when I click out of the Input

```
<ng-select
    [clearable]="true"
    [clearOnBackspace]="true"
    placeholder="Type any three characters for auto-suggest"
    [items]="searchData.fullName.options"
    bindLabel="value"
    bindValue="key"
    name="InputValueName"
    (search)="loadsuggest('fullName', 'persons', $event)"
    loadingText="Loading..."
    formControlName="fullName"
    [loading]="searchData.fullName.loading">
</ng-select>
```

Comment: Do you want to add the entered value to the dropdown when the user clicks outside?

Comment: I already use [addTag] = true for keeping the data, but it's so weir not like HTML input! and if there are no way to resolve this issue how can I bind data to func if I use [addTag]

Comment: hi Ramesh, I know the entered event you are recommend by using [addTag],  but I want mine be like normal HTML input!

Comment: you can use a function with addTag to do some validation if that's what you want, what do you mean when you say normal html input?

Comment: if I use [isOpen]=false It can work like normal input html, but my live suggest search not work (data not load for select)

Comment: You don't want to open the dropdown when the user clicks on the select but want to open it if he/she enters existing values?

Comment: I do want to, but the data if not exist the dropdown will not show, and the value you typed (did not match the data) must be keep

Comment: maybe I will use [addTag] if no way to solve, and if I use [addTag] how can I bind the value ? My value before binding by using this func (search)="loadsuggest('fullName', 'persons', $event)"  the $event.term is my input value

Comment: if you use addTag with a function you can get the entered value as an argument, so you can use the parameter you receive to bind or whatever. See the stackBlitz examples [tags](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/tags) [bindings](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/bindings).

Answer (score 0):

In most biz cases, when the desired value is not a part of the dropdown, the recommended behavior is to select "not in list" in the dropdown and provide a separate text box for entering that. Once the user has provided the value, try to validate that for sanctity and then probably add it to the data set for future selection.

For example, when rolling out a Form where user needs to select a US state and the audience is global, you have a value saying "Outside US" and then provide a textbox. This also frees you from having a huge dataset.

Overtime, using the data analysis, you cna figure out additional values to be added to you dataset.